# How can I see or validate mining in regtest mode?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, testnet, regtest, merkle-tree

I can generate new blocks using ***generate number_of_blocks_that_you_want***. I have 2 nodes running on regtest mode. I sent few coins from one node(wallet) to another. Transaction successful. Status it was showing was Sent and Received  in respective wallets for this transaction But not confirmed yet.  Now If I create New block i.e. mine new block then How can I see or validate that the transaction I have just created is included in the newly mined block? Just as we can see on Explorer. I can see that newly mined block has taken the transaction fess.But what about Merkle root and Merkle path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitcoind, change to txindex=1](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53496/bitcoind-change-to-txindex-1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getblock <block hash>` command to see the details of a block.